# Creating a 'truly global' integer variable using Web API Storage

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I have two html documents, and I want them to share a variable and its value.

In lieu of 'truly global' variables in JavaScript, I've tried employing Web API Storage:

```
        var number = parseInt(localStorage.setItem('num',0));
```

Storage is always a string, so I try parsing into an integer seemingly incorrectly (rather than showing up as 0 in my program, it shows up as 'NaN'). I can only assume that my syntax's wrong?

I want this variable to be increaseable (+1 every time the user clicks on something) but have not yet figured this out. I then want to retrieve its value in the second html document. But due to the initial misstep in attempting to parse the storage value I cannot yet attempt these methods.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem` is used to add values you're probably looking for `localStorage.getItem`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that because `localStorage.setItem` returns `undefined`. The way to do it would be:

```
// define variable
var num = 0;

// set to storage
localStorage.setItem('num', num);

// get from storage
num = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('num'));

// write-back incremented
localStorage.setItem('num', num + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.setItem` stores the value but doesn't return anything - or in other words returns `undefined`. Trying to parse `undefined` as a number returns `NaN`.

Note that localStorage does not work across files when viewing files in your browser from `file://`, you'll need to run a minimal server to test your code.